# Grouping lines with a specific pattern into one line as a csv text file

Tags: php, csv, parsing, multidimensional-array, text-parsing

I'm writing a parser for text data. I've almost done... but it's turn to be the php script must be working on a server with PHP Version 5.3.13. And there is no way to upgrage. So I try to re-write the script but... I think I broke it. It doesn't work at all.

First here is the source text data that I need to parse:

```
27 may 15:28 Id: 42 #1 Random Text

Info: 3 Location: Street Guests: 2              



(Text header 1) Apple                    15
(Text header 2) Milk          2
(Text header 1) Ice cream                   4
(Text header 3) Pencil            1
(Text header 1) Box                    1
   (Text header 2) Cardboard                 x1
   (Text header 3) White                 x1
   (Text header 1) Cube              x1
(Text header 1) Phone     1
   (Text header 1) Specific text                x1
   (Text header 1) Symbian                x1
```

Second here is the desired output, the result text file that I need:

```
42 ; 15:28
Apple ; 15 ; NOHANDLE ; NOHANDLE
Milk ; 2 ; NOHANDLE ; NOHANDLE
Ice cream ; 4 ; NOHANDLE ; NOHANDLE
Pencil ; 1 ; NOHANDLE ; NOHANDLE
Box ; 1 ; Cardboard, White, Cube ; NOHANDLE
Phone ; 1 ; Symbian ; Specific text
```

NOHANDLE is necessary 'cause it is, as you can see, a CSV file. In order for a CSV to work properly, each line needs to have the same number of columns. So I have to add NOHADLE everytime when there is no "child" strings.

And, finaly, here is the I code I try to get work right way:

```
<?php

$data = trim(file_get_contents('inbox_file_utf8_clean.txt'));


$all_lines = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $data);
$date_id_line = array_shift($all_lines);
if(!preg_match('/^\d+\s\w+\s(?<time>\d+:\d+)\sId:\s(?<id>\d+).*/', $date_id_line, $matches)) {
  trigger_error('Failed to match ID and timestamp', E_USER_ERROR);
}
$output_data = array(
  'info' => array(
    'id' => $matches['id'],
    'time' => $matches['time']
  ),
  'data' => array()
);

$all_text_headers = array_values(preg_grep('/^\s*\(/', $all_lines));

// The first "Text header" is a parent.
// Count the number of leading whitespaces to determine other parents
preg_match('/^\x20*/', $all_text_headers[0], $leading_space_matches);
$leading_spaces = $leading_space_matches[0];
$num_leading_spaces = strlen($leading_spaces);
$parent_lead = str_repeat(' ', $num_leading_spaces) . '(';
$parent = NULL;
foreach($all_text_headers as $index => $header_line) {
  array($lead, $item_value) = explode( ") ", $header_line);
  array($topic, $topic_count) = array_map('trim',
    preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $item_value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
  );

  $topic_count = (int) $topic_count;

  if($is_parent = ($parent === NULL || strpos($lead, $parent_lead) === 0)) {
    $parent = $topic;
  }

  // This only goes one level deep
  if($is_parent) {
    $output_data['data'][$parent] = array(
      'values' => array(),
      'count' => $topic_count
    );
  } else {
    $output_data['data'][$parent]['values'][] = $topic;
  }
};

$csv_delimiter = ';';

$handle = fopen('output_file.csv', 'wb');

fputcsv($handle, array_values($output_data['info']), $csv_delimiter);

foreach($output_data['data'] as $key => $values) {

  $row = [
    $key,
    $values['count'],
    implode(', ', $values['values']) ?: 'NOHANDLE',
    'NOHANDLE'
  ];
  fputcsv($handle, $row, $csv_delimiter);
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Now I stuck... I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in index.php on line 29
```

Comment: `array($lead, $item_value) = explode( ") ", $header_line);` this is not valid syntax.

Comment: well... how to correct that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your requirements are a bit unclear. Can you explain the logic that determines whether children are comma-delimited or semicolon-delimited? It looks like when two share "text header 1", they are semicolon-delimited, but I can't tell how this should be organized in more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're right you must use **array()** insted of just **[ ]**

and the error line

```
array($lead, $item_value) = explode( ") ", $header_line);
```

must be like this:

```
list($lead, $item_value) = explode(') ', $header_line);
```

and in the next line you must use **list ()**

i try to make all corrections:

```
<?php

$data = trim(file_get_contents('inbox_file_utf8_clean.txt'));


$all_lines = preg_split("/\r?\n/", $data);
$date_id_line = array_shift($all_lines);
if(!preg_match('/^\d+\s\w+\s(?<time>\d+:\d+)\sId:\s(?<id>\d+).*/', $date_id_line, $matches)) {
  trigger_error('Failed to match ID and timestamp', E_USER_ERROR);
}
$output_data = array(
  'info' => array(
    'id' => $matches['id'],
    'time' => $matches['time']
  ),
  'data' => array()
);

$all_text_headers = array_values(preg_grep('/^\s*\(/', $all_lines));

// The first "Text header" is a parent.
// Count the number of leading whitespaces to determine other parents
preg_match('/^\x20*/', $all_text_headers[0], $leading_space_matches);
$leading_spaces = $leading_space_matches[0];
$num_leading_spaces = strlen($leading_spaces);
$parent_lead = str_repeat(' ', $num_leading_spaces) . '(';
$parent = NULL;
foreach($all_text_headers as $index => $header_line) {
  list($lead, $item_value) = explode(') ', $header_line);
  list($topic, $topic_count) = array_map('trim',
    preg_split('/\s{2,}/', $item_value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
  );

  $topic_count = (int) $topic_count;

  if($is_parent = ($parent === NULL || strpos($lead, $parent_lead) === 0)) {
    $parent = $topic;
  }

  // This only goes one level deep
  if($is_parent) {
    $output_data['data'][$parent] = array(
      'values' => array(),
      'count' => $topic_count
    );
  } else {
    $output_data['data'][$parent]['values'][] = $topic;
  }
};

$csv_delimiter = ';';

$handle = fopen('output_file.csv', 'wb');

fputcsv($handle, array_values($output_data['info']), $csv_delimiter);

foreach($output_data['data'] as $key => $values) {

  $row = array(
    $key,
    $values['count'],
    implode(', ', $values['values']) ?: 'NOHANDLE',
    'NOHANDLE'
  );
  fputcsv($handle, $row, $csv_delimiter);
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: It works! thanks! but there is no number assigned to "child" line.